# python intersection of lists while not having the same index

Tags: python

I have a curious case, and after some time I have not come up with an adequate solution.

Say you have two lists and you need to find items that have the same index.

```
x = [1,4,5,7,8]
y = [1,3,8,7,9]
```

I am able to get a correct intersection of those which appear in both lists with the same index by using the following:

```
matches = [i for i, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(x,y)) if a==b)
```

This would return:

```
[0,3]
```

I am able to get a a simple intersection of both lists with the following (and in many other ways, this is just an example)

```
intersected = set(x) & set(y)
```

This would return this list:

```
[1,8,7,9]
```

Here's the question.   I'm wondering for some ideas for a way of getting a list of items (as in the second list) which do not include those matches above but are not in the same position on the list.

In other words, I'm looking items in x that do not share the same index in the y

The desired result would be the index position of "8" in y, or  `[2]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"In other words, I'm looking items in x that do not share the same index in the y"* - do you mean items in both `x` AND `y` that do not share the same index?

Comment: yes that is it exactly

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close: iterate through `y`; look for a value that is in `x`, but *not* at the same position:

```
offset = [i for i, a in enumerate(y) if a in x and a != x[i] ]
```

Result:

```
[2]
```

Including the suggested upgrade from `pault`, with respect to `Martijn's` comment ... the pre-processing reduces the complexity, in case of large lists:

```
>>> both = set(x) & set(y)
>>> offset = [i for i, a in enumerate(y) if a in both and a != x[i] ]
```

As PaulT pointed out, this is still quite readable at OP's posted level.

Comment: This does a quadratic scan of `x`, each `a in x` test must iterate through `x` to see if there is a match.

Comment: Yes, it's quadratic.  It's also accessible to less advanced programmers, in line with OP's attempts.  However, it's good that you took the high road with the "learning stretch" and a more efficient algorithm in case of large lists.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I was trying a zillion variations of this but my brain quit on me.

Comment: You're quite welcome ... but I *do* recommend that you read Martijn's answer (and his comment here) and learn from it.

Comment: You could precompute the intersection to avoid the quadratic lookups.

Comment: @pault: Right ... this is what Martijn does in his answer (which I've already up-voted ... hint to others).  I'm leaving mine intact as it's closest to OP's original logic.

Comment: ok actually I found a problem with this approach.  If x is for instance [1,3,3] it's giving me [2] which is not what I want.  I get how it might, but I'd like it to find items which do not exist in another position.  In other words, it's having trouble with items that are duplicated in the list.

Comment: @Prune I agree with you, but you could keep close to OP's original logic with `intersected = set(x) & set(y)` and do `[... if a in intersected ...]`.

Comment: @nomistic: No, it returns the empty list for that: there is no element of `y` that is found in `x`, but not at its own position.  Did you perhaps reverse `x` and `y`?  If so, then my solution still matches your stated goal: elements that are found in the other set, but not at their position in the target set.

Comment: ok, I must be not explaining myself.   I'll update the question above (I saw your update, but it's also having the same issue)

Comment: as suspected it was me.  I must have made a mistake.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a dictionary of indices for the first list, then use that to test if the second value is a) in that dictionary, and b) the current index is not present:

```
def non_matching_indices(x, y):
    x_indices = {}
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        x_indices.setdefault(v, set()).add(i)

    return [i for i, v in enumerate(y) if i not in x_indices.get(v, {i})]
```

The above takes `O(len(x) + len(y))` time; a single full scan through the one list, then another full scan through the other, where each test to include `i` is done in constant time.

You really don't want to use a `value in x` containment test here, because that requires a scan (a loop) over `x` to see if that value is really in the list or not. That takes `O(len(x))` time, and you do that for each value in `y`, which means that the fucntion takes `O(len(x) * len(y))` time.

You can see the speed differences when you run a time trial with a larger list filled with random data:

```
>>> import random, timeit
>>> def using_in_x(x, y):
...     return [i for i, a in enumerate(y) if a in x and a != x[i]]
...
>>> x = random.sample(range(10**6), 1000)
>>> y = random.sample(range(10**6), 1000)
>>> for f in (using_in_x, non_matching_indices):
...     timer = timeit.Timer("f(x, y)", f"from __main__ import f, x, y")
...     count, total = timer.autorange()
...     print(f"{f.__name__:>20}: {total / count * 1000:6.3f}ms")
...
          using_in_x: 10.468ms
non_matching_indices:  0.630ms
```

So with two lists of 1000 numbers each, if you use `value in x` testing, you easily take 15 times as much time to complete the task.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = [1,4,5,7,8]
y = [1,3,8,7,9]

result=[]
for e in x:
    if e in y and x.index(e) != y.index(e):
        result.append((x.index(e),y.index(e),e))

print result  #gives tuple with x_position,y_position,value
```

This version goes item by item through the first list and checks whether the item is also in the second list. If it is, it compares the indices for the found item in both lists and if they are different then it stores both indices and the item value as a tuple with three values in the result list.

Comment: Do not use `list.index()`! That only gives you the index of the *first* occurrence of the value, so if you have repeated values in `x` or in `y` then you'll get incorrect results.

Comment: Next, don't use `e in y` here, because that does a full scan of `y` for each value in `x`. This makes your approach take O(NM) time (cubic time), with a higher constant factor inside the loop than the other two O(NM) answers here so far, because you use 4 `.index()` calls.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22053400)